# Как исправить ошибку: "all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly"?

Tags: python, дата, машинное-обучение, обработка-ошибок

Даны данные размерностью 374 строки x 31 столбца. Первый столбец это дата, остальные столбцы - цены акций 30 компаний. Нужно применить метод главных компонент. Для этого написал следующий код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Location1 = r'C:\Users\...\close_prices.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location1)
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = df.drop('date', 1)
pca = PCA(n_components=10)
pca.fit(X)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
# первая компонента объясняет больше всего вариации признаков (цены 30-ти компаний)
# теперь применяю преобразование к исходным данным
X1 = pca.transform(X)
X1.shape
# (374, 10)
# необходимо взять первую компоненту => я беру (374, 1)
X11 = X1[:,0]
X11.shape
# (374,)
```

Ошибка возникает когда хочу посчитать коэффициент корреляции Пирсона

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('djia_index.csv')
X2 = df2.drop('date', 1)
X2.shape
#(374, 1)
from numpy import corrcoef
corr1 = corrcoef(X2, X11)
```

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Почему размерность не совпадает, и как её исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю как объяснить то как результат у меня получился. Если кто-то знает причину или значение такой конструкции данных:

```
np.array([[],[],...,[]])
```

Просьба написать об этом в комментариях.

решение было таким, я просто транспонировал оба вектора (или матрицы столбцы)

```
X11 = X11.T
X2 = X2.T
corr1 = corrcoef(X11, X2)
corr1
array([[ 1.        ,  0.90965222],
   [ 0.90965222,  1.        ]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Проще и быстрее показать на примере, чем описывать словами:

```
In [62]: A = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

In [63]: A
Out[63]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [64]: A[:, 0]
Out[64]: array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20])

In [65]: A[:, 0].shape
Out[65]: (5,)

In [66]: A[:, [0]]
Out[66]:
array([[ 0],
       [ 5],
       [10],
       [15],
       [20]])

In [67]: A[:, [0]].shape
Out[67]: (5, 1)
```

проблема с `np.corrcoef()` возникает по-моему при расчете ковариационной матрицы: `np.cov()` и, похоже, при расчете `np.cov()` для матрицы состоящей из единственного столбца всегда получается матрица, состоящая из всех `nan`:

```
In [149]: x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,1))

In [150]: x
Out[150]:
array([[4],
       [7],
       [3],
       [0],
       [0]])

In [151]: np.cov(x)
c:\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2487: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  warnings.warn("Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice", RuntimeWarning)
Out[151]:
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [152]: x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,2))

In [153]: x
Out[153]:
array([[7, 0],
       [0, 8],
       [4, 2],
       [1, 5],
       [7, 1]])

In [154]: np.cov(x)
Out[154]:
array([[ 24.5, -28. ,   7. , -14. ,  21. ],
       [-28. ,  32. ,  -8. ,  16. , -24. ],
       [  7. ,  -8. ,   2. ,  -4. ,   6. ],
       [-14. ,  16. ,  -4. ,   8. , -12. ],
       [ 21. , -24. ,   6. , -12. ,  18. ]])
```

Comment: Получается мне нужно эти две матрицы состоящие из одного столбца (X2 и X11) объединить в матрицу с двумя столбцами

Comment: array([[7, 0],
       [0, 8],
       [4, 2],
       [1, 5],
       [7, 1]])   ?

Comment: @user214410, можно попробовать... Я до этого не работал с  "коэффициентом корреляции Пирсона", поэтому не совсем понимаю, что должно получиться в результате...

Comment: Я попробую, результат напишу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка отмеченная выше была следствием несовпадения размерности X2 (374, 1) и X11 (374,). 
Потому что когда я добавил скобки к команде `X11 = X1[:,0]` то я получил нужную размерность которая в точности совпадает с размерностью X2 (374, 1)

```
X11 = X1[:,[0]]
X11.shape
# (374, 1)
```

Затем я опять попробовал вычислить коэффициент регрессии Пирсона:

```
 corr1 = corrcoef(X2, X11)
 C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2079:RuntimeWarning: 
Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice warnings.warn("Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice", RuntimeWarning)
```

Но появилось следующее сообщение. Что это значит?
Почему если я поставил дополнительные скобки то появилась отсутствующая колонка?
При этом вся матрица коэффициентов корреляции состоит из nan!

```
 corr1
 Out[48]: 
 array([[ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   ..., 
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

nan во всей матрице берутся из-за структуры данных переменной Х11. В них есть отрицательные значения. А так как коэффициент корреляции Пирсона считается:
[image: Пирсоновские коэффициенты корреляции считаются по формуле]

Но откуда взялись отрицательные значения вообще?

Comment: Я пока не пробовал соединить в одну матрицу два вектора (поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь в названии). Потому что не знаю как тогда задать функцию корреляции. 
Но я поэкспериментировал и пришел к выводу что вторые квадратные скобки внутри вектора мешают (я пока не знаю что они обозначают).
    X = [0,0,1,1,0]
    Y = [1,1,0,1,1]
даёт результат
array([[ 1.        , -0.61237244],
       [-0.61237244,  1.        ]])
    Y = [[1],[1],[0],[1],[1]]
    X = [[0],[0],[1],[1],[0]]
даёт результат nan: array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,...]]