# Почему используя метод главных компонент при применении построенного преобразования к исходным данным получаются отрицательные значения?

Tags: python, transform, машинное-обучение

Даны данные размерностью 374 строки x 31 столбца. Первый столбец это дата, остальные столбцы цены акций 30 компаний. Мне нужно применить метод главных компонент. Для этого я написал следующий код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Location1 = r'C:\Users\...\close_prices.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location1)
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = df.drop('date', 1)
pca = PCA(n_components=10)
pca.fit(X)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
# первая компонента объясняет больше всего вариации признаков (цены 30-ти компаний)
# теперь применяю преобразование к исходным данным
X1 = pca.transform(X)
X1
Out[7]:
array([[-50.90240358, -17.63167724,  -7.7360209 , ...,   3.55657041,
     -5.82197358,  -1.72604005],
   [-52.84690919, -19.14690749,  -7.27254551, ...,   3.43259929,
     -5.63318106,  -2.0122316 ],
X1.shape
# (374, 10)
# необходимо взять первую компоненту и рассчитать коэфициент корреляции Пирсона для Индекса Доу Джонса размерностью (374, 1) => я беру (374, 1)
X11 = X1[:,[0]]
X11.shape
# (374,1)
```

Но я не могу посчитать коэффициент так как числа отрицательные в Х1. Поэтому при взятия корня и деления матрица получается с nan.

Почему после применения обученной модели к Х получается матрица с отрицательными значениями?

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает умножить результат на -1? PCA выделяет направления в пространстве признаков, в то время как ориентация собственных векторов, задающих эти направления, особой роли не играет.

Comment: Верно, но у меня имеются и положительные данные, поэтому отрицательные значения останутся. Я решил проблем, но не до конца понимая как.
@q-dad [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548294/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-all-the-input-array-dimensions-except-for-the-concatenatio/548364#548364)
если будет интересно, ответ на проблему там